# How to force JQuery to make an HTTP 1.0 request and close the connection

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to jQuery and would like to make a POST request using plain HTTP 1.0 with connection close, instead of the HTTP 1.1 connections that is currently kept alive.

Below is an is the onClick handler for the button that does the post.

```
$( "#certGenBtn" ).click( function( event ) {
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:9099/",
  data: { testVal : "data" },
  success: function( data ) {
              alert( "whoops" );
           },
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                  xhr.setRequestHeader( "Connection", "close" );
              }
    });
});
```

The raw output dumped on the server side is the following:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9099
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-ZA,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/  
Content-Length: 12
Origin: http://localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

testVal=data
```

The Connection close header is being 'ignored' and the connection remains open to the server so the very last line `testVal=data` only gets through once i reload the page (I assume this is because the connection is then closed by the browser). I assume it's something very simple and/or stupid that I'm missing but cannot see anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) According to the HTTP 1.1 spec, `Connection: close` is a valid header:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

How about trying to add it with the headers key instead of beforeSend?

```
.ajax({

   ....
   headers: {Connection: close},

});
```

2) The jquery docs specify the following function signature for the beforeSend function:

```
beforeSend 
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, PlainObject settings )
```

So you might also try adding the header to the settings object rather than the jqXHR object.

Well, I tested your original code as well as my suggestions, and none of them succeed.  It looks like the XMLHttpRequest spec forbids setting the Connection header:

> The setRequestHeader(header, value) method must run these steps:
>
> Terminate these steps if header is a case-insensitive match for one of
>   the following headers:
>
> ... 
>   Connection
>   ...
>
> The above headers are controlled by the user agent to let it control
>   those aspects of transport. This guarantees data integrity to some
>   extent.
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method

Comment: Thank you very much!, 
I had the same results on my side, is there a way to force HTTP 1.0 instead of HTTP 1.1? AFAIK `Connection: keep-alive` is a HTTP 1.1 specific and it's not present in HTTP 1.0.

Comment: "the user agent" means your browser.  I think you would have to figure out a way to configure your browser to use HTTP 1.0--but what's the point unless the js is strictly for personal use.  I looked around Firefox 21.0, and I didn't see a setting.

Comment: I'm not referring to the user agent part, the very first line of the response the server receives reads `POST / HTTP/1.1`, that indicates the browser is making the request using the HTTP 1.1 protocol instead of HTTP 1.0. If I could only force the client to use HTTP 1.0 instead of HTTP 1.1 then the whole concept of keep alive falls away (the Connection header is not in the HTTP 1.0 spec) [link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html)

Comment: 1) The server doesn't receive a response.  2)Who do you think sent the request that has the header POST / HTTP/1.1  (Hint: your browser, i.e. "the user agent"?

Comment: i think we're misunderstanding each other, the server does indeed receive the request the header dump was taken on the server side. The problem is the server (a very limited embedded server) does not support the full HTTP 1.1 feature set and because the connection is being kept alive by the browser the server does not get the final part of the post data until the connection is closed.

Comment: Okay, but the issue is how do you make your browser send an HTTP 1.0 request.  An html <form> tag does not allow you to specify the HTTP protocol, and as we've seen at XMLHttpRequest can't set the Connection header when sending a request--because the browser retains control over what protocol is used.  So as far as I can tell, you have to open your browser's preferences and see if there is a setting for the HTTP protocol.  Otherwise, you have to downgrade your browser to a version that uses the HTTP 1.0 protocol.

Comment: yup, that seems the only way the browser is in full control, if you can post it as an answer i'll accept

Comment: @user2477684, all the comments are part of the answer.

Comment: `Connection: close` can't be set with JavaScript, it will be overwritten with `Connection: keep-alive`

Answer (score 1):

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function(msg){
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});

//kill the request
xhr.abort()
```